# Finding duplicates in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, duplicates

The following code results in an `Array`:

```
[Array]$Object = [PSCustomObject]@{
    P1 = 'Appel'
    P2 = 'Cherry'
    P3 = 'Appel'
    P4 = 'Banana'    
}
$Object += [PSCustomObject]@{
    P1 = 'Good'
    P2 = 'Bad'
    P3 = 'Good'
    P4 = 'Good'
}
$Object += [PSCustomObject]@{
    P1 = 'Green'
    P2 = 'Red'
    P3 = 'Green'
    P4 = 'Yellow'
}
$Object
```

This generates:

```
P1         P2         P3       P4                          
--         --         --       --                          
Appel      Cherry     Appel    Banana                      
Good       Bad        Good     Good                        
Green      Red        Green    Yellow
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can have it report the duplicates, in this case the **desired outcome** would be `P1` and `P3` as they both have the same info in them:

```
P1      P3                       
--      --                       
Appel   Appel                    
Good    Good                     
Green   Green
```

Because the values are not in the same object it's not as simple as using `Group-Object` to retrieve them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something along the lines of `if (!(Compare-Object $object.p1 $object.p3)) { echo duplicate }`?

Comment: Yes arco444, that's what I'm playing with now.`Compare-Object $Object.P1 $Object.P3 -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent`. I only need to figure out how to loop through the collection to have it compare everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

```
$Props = $Object | Get-Member | ? MemberType -EQ NoteProperty | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count

$Result = for ($a = 1; $a -le $Props; $a++) {
    for ($b = 1; $b -le $Props; $b++) {
        if ($a -ne $b) {
            if (($R = Compare-Object ([String[]]$Object.("P$a")) ([String[]]$Object.("P$b")) -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent).Count -eq 3) {
                $R.InputObject | Out-String
            }
        }
    }
}

$Result | Select-Object -Unique
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `Group-Object` to find duplicate property values in each object by inspecting the value of each entry in the `psobject.Properties` property:

```
PS C:\> $Object |ForEach-Object {
    $_.psobject.Properties | Group-Object { $_.Value } | Format-Table
}

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 Appel                     {string P1=Appel, string P3=Appel}
    1 Cherry                    {string P2=Cherry}
    1 Banana                    {string P4=Banana}


Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    3 Good                      {string P1=Good, string P3=Good, string P4=Good}
    1 Bad                       {string P2=Bad}


Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 Green                     {string P1=Green, string P3=Green}
    1 Red                       {string P2=Red}
    1 Yellow                    {string P4=Yellow}
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias for putting me on the right track, but I really need to compare all 3 values to see if they all 3 match..

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you trying to accomplish here. None of the 3 objects in your `$Object` array have duplicates between them

Comment: You are correct, the values are not in the same object. I've updated the OP to be more clear.

Comment: Yes, but what about the `P4` property then? It has a duplicate value in the second object

Comment: I don't care about that, it only interests me if all 3 property values are equal.